# Some of the In-App purchases are not listing & shows "This In-App purchase has already been bought"

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

In our app we have the following features,

- List available In-App purchases,
- Buy,
- Download &
- List my purchased In-App purchases.

**Note*** I have called `SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)` only once.

**Problem:**

"Listing my purchased In-App purchases" causes problem like only few purchases are returned in the following delegate method(`func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])`) which gets called while calling `SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()`

- I can check our "Purchase History" and its available there. But not getting listed in the app.

Also when I download the same In-App purchase again its saying "This In-App purchase has already been brought".

I tried re-installing the app, still the problem exists.

**Note*** I have also tried using third party library "[SwiftyStoreKit](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit)"
still the same issue exists ?

Don't know whats causing the issue. Any idea whats causing the issue ?

Comment: Please check in App purchase types , consumable , non consumable , subscription, and used suitable type of your app may be you have select wrong one.

Comment: @JatinKathrotiya: Ya, I too thought that so, I have checked that and all the In-App purchases are of type "Non-Consumable" so there is no expiration which eliminates few possibilities of this issue.

Comment: non-consumable is like purchase one time and used it life time so any non consumable product will not take charge when buy again and you should also ned to put restore button other wise your app will be rejected. 

User  need to pay every-time for  Consumable product,  example purchase of Coins, hints , Jams etc ..

Comment: @Jatin : Yes I have restore purchases button too. The problem I'm facing is while restoring I get only few in app purchases.

Answer (score 0):

Each receipt can contain an array of purchases - all you need is the latest receipt to see all the previous ones. Also, in-app-purchases are linked to your App Store account so they will persist through uninstalling and reinstalling your app.

Are the purchases you're seeing in `updatedTransactions` just the unique product IDs?

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing the unique ids in updatedTransactions. And regarding the receipts, there is no need for me to use receipts since it's non consumable purchases

Comment: Non-consumable purchases are meant to be bought once and unlock content forever. So Apple saying "This In-App purchase has already been brought" is the expected behavior - you can only buy a non-consumable purchase once. In `updatedTransactions` you should only see the unique product IDs that you've purchased.

Comment: Ya, as you stated the behaviour is fine. But the last statement you mentioned i.e, the unique product IDs which I get from '''updatedTransactions''' doesn't have all the purchased items it only has few that is the issue I am facing.